# on back press from payment gateway clear all the user data or information in android

Tags: android

In my application when i passes the details of user for the first time it successfully reached to payment gateway page but when it done to second time it unfortunately stop. I want..On back press from atom payment gateway it should clear all the user data or information how it will be done....please help me I am new in android arena

---

Here is my code where I am passing the user details and i integrated ATOM payment gateway library in which PayActivity.java class file is already defined

ActivityPaymentOption.java

```
package com.adeveloper.www.prashant;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;

import com.atom.mobilepaymentsdk.PayActivity;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


/**
 * Created by Dev on 10/1/2015.
 */

public class ActivityPaymentOption extends Fragment{

    private RadioGroup radioPaymentGroup;
    private RadioButton radioCOD,radioON;
    private Button placeOrder;
    private TextView textView;
    View view;
    ProgressDialog pdialog;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String getCustomerDataResult;
    String getCustomerDataResult2;
    String getCustomerDataResult3;
    String getCustomerDataResult4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        Constants.lastDetails = true;
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment_option, container, false);
        //Set Navigation mode as Statndard
        //((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        view = v;

        radioPaymentGroup = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.radioPaymentMethod);

        placeOrder = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlaceOrder);
        radioCOD = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radioCOD);
        radioON = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radioON);
        //textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textShipping);

        placeOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                int selectedId = radioPaymentGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                // find the radiobutton by returned id
                if(selectedId == radioCOD.getId()) {
                    radioCOD = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(selectedId);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), radioCOD.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    new getDataTask().execute();
                } else if(selectedId == radioON.getId()) {
                    radioON = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(selectedId);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), radioON.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Intent newPayIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MPSActivity.class);
                    //startActivity(newPayIntent);
                    new getData().execute();
                    }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            MainActivity.getInstance().CallFragment(Constants.position);
        }
        return true;
    }
    public class getData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (pdialog==null){
                pdialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                pdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(getRetainInstance());
                pdialog.setCancelable(false);
                pdialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // parse json data from server in background
            shoppingCartShippingMethod();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (pdialog.isShowing()){
                pdialog.dismiss();
                pdialog=null;
            }
            if (getCustomerDataResult4!=null){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Order Placed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            else

            Constants.OrderNo = Integer.parseInt(getCustomerDataResult4);
            Intent newPayIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PayActivity.class);

            newPayIntent.putExtra("merchantId", "11111");
            newPayIntent.putExtra("txnscamt", "0"); //Fixed. Must be �0�
            newPayIntent.putExtra("loginid", "11111");
            newPayIntent.putExtra("password", "PRASH@123");
            newPayIntent.putExtra("prodid", "PRASH");
            newPayIntent.putExtra("txncurr", "INR"); //Fixed. Must be �INR�
            newPayIntent.putExtra("clientcode", "007");
            newPayIntent.putExtra("custacc", "100000036600");
            newPayIntent.putExtra("amt", ActivityCart.TotalProductCartPrice);//Should be 3 decimal number i.e 1.000
            newPayIntent.putExtra("txnid", "XX");
            newPayIntent.putExtra("date", "25/08/2015 18:31:00");//Should be in same format
            newPayIntent.putExtra("bankid", ""); //Should be valid bank id

            //use below Production url only with Production "Library-MobilePaymentSDK", Located inside PROD folder
            newPayIntent.putExtra("ru", "https://payment.atomtech.in/mobilesdk/param"); //ru FOR Production

            //use below UAT url only with UAT "Library-MobilePaymentSDK", Located inside UAT folder
            //newPayIntent.putExtra("ru", "https://paynetzuat.atomtech.in/mobilesdk/param"); // FOR UAT (Testing)

            //Optinal Parameters
            newPayIntent.putExtra("customerName", ActivityCustomerAddress.FirstName); //Only for Name
            newPayIntent.putExtra("customerEmailID", Constants.Customer_Email);//Only for Email ID
            newPayIntent.putExtra("customerMobileNo",ActivityCustomerAddress.contact);//Only for Mobile Number
            newPayIntent.putExtra("billingAddress", ActivityCustomerAddress.City);//Only for Address
            newPayIntent.putExtra("optionalUdf9", "OPTIONAL DATA 1");// Can pass any data

            startActivityForResult(newPayIntent, 1);

        }
    }
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Constants.lastDetails = false;
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(null);
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

   }
    public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
        try {
            File dir = context.getCacheDir();
            deleteDir(dir);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return dir.delete();
        } else if(dir!= null && dir.isFile()) {
            return dir.delete();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }






    public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (pdialog==null){
                pdialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                pdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(getRetainInstance());
                pdialog.setCancelable(false);
                pdialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // parse json data from server in background
            shoppingCartShippingMethod();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (pdialog.isShowing()){
                pdialog.dismiss();
                pdialog=null;
            }

            if (getCustomerDataResult4!=null){

               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Order Placed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else

                Constants.OrderNo = Integer.parseInt(getCustomerDataResult4);
            OrderConfirmation orderConfirmation=new OrderConfirmation();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content,orderConfirmation,null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            getActivity().setTitle("Order");
        }
    }

    // method to set shopping Cart Shipping Method
    public void shoppingCartShippingMethod(){

        try {
            // add paramaters and values
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartShippingMethod");
            request.addProperty("sessionId", Constants.sessionId);
            request.addProperty("quoteId", Constants.cartId);
            request.addProperty("method", "flatrate_flatrate");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            //Web method call
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);
            //get the response
            String result = String.valueOf(envelope.getResponse());
            getCustomerDataResult2 = result.toString();

//            // Call shopping Cart Payment Method
            if(getCustomerDataResult2.equals("true")){
                shoppingCartPaymentMethod();
            }
            else {
                getCustomerDataResult = "false";
                return;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // method to set shopping Cart Payment Method
    public void shoppingCartPaymentMethod(){

        try {

            SoapObject PaymentMethodEntity = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartPaymentMethodEntity");

            PaymentMethodEntity.addProperty("method","cashondelivery");

            // add paramaters and values
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartPaymentMethod");
            request.addProperty("sessionId", Constants.sessionId);
            request.addProperty("quoteId", Constants.cartId);
            request.addProperty("method", PaymentMethodEntity);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            //Web method call
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);
            //get the response
            String result = String.valueOf(envelope.getResponse());
            getCustomerDataResult3 = result.toString();

//            // Call Place shopping Cart Order
            if(getCustomerDataResult3.equals("true")){
                shoppingCartOrder();
            }
            else {
                getCustomerDataResult = "false";
                return;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // method to Place shopping Cart Order
    public void shoppingCartOrder(){

        try {
            // add paramaters and values
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartOrder");
            request.addProperty("sessionId", Constants.sessionId);
            request.addProperty("quoteId", Constants.cartId);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            //Web method call
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);
            //get the response
            String result = String.valueOf(envelope.getResponse());
            getCustomerDataResult4 = result.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

---

PayActivity.java

package com.atom.mobilepaymentsdk;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.InputFilter.LengthFilter;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PayActivity extends Activity {
    private String a = "";
    private String b = "";
    private String c = "";
    private String d = "";
    private String e = "";
    private String f = "";
    private String g = "";
    private String h = "";
    private String i = "";
    private String j = "";
    private String k = "";
    private String l = "";
    private String m = "";
    private String n = "";
    private String o = "";
    private String p = "";
    private String q = "";
    private String r = "";
    private String s = "";
    private String t = "";
    private String u = "";

    public PayActivity() {
    }

    private static String a(String var0) {
        String var1 = null;
        if(var0 != null) {
            var1 = var0.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        }

        return var1;
    }

    private static String b(String var0) {
        String var1 = "";
        if(var0 != null) {
            var1 = var0.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        }

        return var1;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle var1) {
        super.onCreate(var1);
        Intent var22 = this.getIntent();
        if(this.getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            a.a = false;
            this.a = a(var22.getStringExtra("merchantId"));
            this.b = a(var22.getStringExtra("txnscamt"));
            this.c = a(var22.getStringExtra("loginid"));
            this.d = a(var22.getStringExtra("password"));
            this.e = a(var22.getStringExtra("prodid"));
            this.f = a(var22.getStringExtra("txncurr"));
            this.g = a(var22.getStringExtra("clientcode"));
            this.h = a(var22.getStringExtra("custacc"));
            this.i = a(var22.getStringExtra("channelid"));
            this.j = a(var22.getStringExtra("amt"));
            this.k = a(var22.getStringExtra("txnid"));
            this.l = a(var22.getStringExtra("date"));
            this.m = a(var22.getStringExtra("cardtype"));
            this.n = a(var22.getStringExtra("cardAssociate"));
            this.o = a(var22.getStringExtra("bankid"));
            this.q = b(var22.getStringExtra("customerName"));
            this.r = b(var22.getStringExtra("customerEmailID"));
            this.s = b(var22.getStringExtra("customerMobileNo"));
            this.t = b(var22.getStringExtra("billingAddress"));
            this.u = b(var22.getStringExtra("optionalUdf9"));
            this.p = a(var22.getStringExtra("ru"));
        }

        String var21 = this.u;
        String var20 = this.t;
        String var19 = this.s;
        String var18 = this.r;
        String var17 = this.q;
        String var16 = this.p;
        String var15 = this.i;
        String var14 = this.h;
        String var13 = this.g;
        String var12 = this.f;
        String var11 = this.e;
        String var10 = this.d;
        String var9 = this.c;
        String var8 = this.b;
        String var7 = this.a;
        String var6 = this.n;
        String var5 = this.m;
        String var4 = this.l;
        String var3 = this.k;
        String var2 = this.j;
        d var23;
        if(var5 != null) {
            (var23 = new d(this, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10, var11, var12, var13, var14, var15, var16, var17, var18, var19, var20, var21)).a.setContentView(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("layout_card_payment_screen", "layout", var23.a.getPackageName()));
            ((TextView)var23.a.findViewById(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("payAmount", "id", var23.a.getPackageName()))).setText(var23.u);
            ((ImageView)var23.a.findViewById(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("img_lib_atomlogo", "id", var23.a.getPackageName()))).setBackgroundResource(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("atomlogo", "drawable", var23.a.getPackageName()));
            ImageView var24 = (ImageView)var23.a.findViewById(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("img_cardType", "id", var23.a.getPackageName()));
            TextView var26 = (TextView)var23.a.findViewById(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("tv_Card_Details_Label", "id", var23.a.getPackageName()));
            var23.O = (EditText)var23.a.findViewById(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("et_Card_Name", "id", var23.a.getPackageName()));
            var23.P = (EditText)var23.a.findViewById(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("et_Card_No", "id", var23.a.getPackageName()));
            var23.P.addTextChangedListener(new h(var23));
            if(var23.F.equalsIgnoreCase("VISA")) {
                var24.setBackgroundResource(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("atom_lib_visa", "drawable", var23.a.getPackageName()));
            } else if(var23.F.equalsIgnoreCase("MASTER")) {
                var24.setBackgroundResource(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("atom_lib_master", "drawable", var23.a.getPackageName()));
            } else if(var23.F.equalsIgnoreCase("MAESTRO")) {
                var24.setBackgroundResource(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("atom_lib_maestro", "drawable", var23.a.getPackageName()));
            }

            var23.Q = (EditText)var23.a.findViewById(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("et_CVV", "id", var23.a.getPackageName()));
            var23.S = (Spinner)var23.a.findViewById(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("sp_Exp_Year", "id", var23.a.getPackageName()));
            var23.S.setAdapter(new k(var23, var23.a, var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("custom_spinner", "layout", var23.a.getPackageName()), var23.U));
            var23.R = (Spinner)var23.a.findViewById(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("sp_Exp_Month", "id", var23.a.getPackageName()));
            var23.R.setAdapter(new k(var23, var23.a, var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("custom_spinner", "layout", var23.a.getPackageName()), var23.V));
            InputFilter[] var27;
            if(var23.E.equalsIgnoreCase("CC")) {
                var26.setText("CREDIT CARD");
                (var27 = new InputFilter[1])[0] = new LengthFilter(4);
                var23.Q.setFilters(var27);
            } else if(var23.E.equalsIgnoreCase("DC")) {
                var26.setText("DEBIT CARD");
                (var27 = new InputFilter[1])[0] = new LengthFilter(3);
                var23.Q.setFilters(var27);
            }

            Button var25 = (Button)var23.a.findViewById(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("btn_CardPayment_Now", "id", var23.a.getPackageName()));
            Button var28 = (Button)var23.a.findViewById(var23.a.getResources().getIdentifier("btn_CardPayment_Cancel", "id", var23.a.getPackageName()));
            var25.setOnClickListener(new f(var23));
            var28.setOnClickListener(new g(var23));
        } else {
            var23 = new d(this, var2, var3, var4, this.o, var7, var8, var9, var10, var11, var12, var13, var14, var16, var17, var18, var19, var20, var21);
            (new j(var23)).execute(new Integer[0]);
        }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu var1) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int var1, KeyEvent var2) {
        if(var1 == 4) {
            if(!a.a) {
                this.finish();
            }

            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onKeyDown(var1, var2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: override @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  //clear your atom payment gatway data here where you have stored
}

Comment: means in PayActivity.java class I have to use OnBackPressed.

Comment: yes override onbackpress method

Comment: and @pcpriyanka Unable to edit External Library Files - showing as Locked